# Can we check signatures of arbitrary data in plutus validators?

Tags: plutus, validator

I am looking for a function with a type like this:

```
verifySignature :: Datum -> Signature -> PubKey -> Bool
```

which is also INLINABLE to use it inside validator.

I know that we can check if the whole transaction is signed by some pub key with this [function](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/b778f9abbe172177b579badf83b899ee05fda2e0/plutus-ledger-api/src/Plutus/V1/Ledger/Contexts.hs#L233), but this should be an arbitrary message signature, not transaction signature.

Comment: N.B. I want to store signed proof off-chain, so putting this Datum inside some output and singing it is not an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think PlutusTx.Builtins has what you need:

```
{-# INLINABLE verifySignature #-}
-- | Verify that the signature is a signature of the message by the public key.
verifySignature :: BuiltinByteString -> BuiltinByteString -> BuiltinByteString -> Bool
```

You can use verifySignature on-chain. If you do it on chain, then your signature and the PubKeyHash should be either some wrappers around `BuiltinByteString` or directly `BuiltinByteString`. Either way, there should be no problem getting the types needed for `verifySignature`.

Answer (score 3):

There is also an oracle for signature verification [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/804a84bd15074902cce9096ef98721675566c003/plutus-contract/src/Plutus/Contract/Oracle.hs?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container%2C%20div%5Bitemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FSoftwareSourceCode%22%5D%20main%2C%20%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D#L13)